# What is the asymptotic runtime of the below equation?

Tags: asymptotics, big-o-notation

What is the asymptotic of
${n \choose 3} \log ^4n$ ?
I know that ${n \choose 3}$ is in $\cal O (n^3)$, but what about the term $log^4n$ and what about the product of the two?

Comment: A mathematical expression doesn't have a "runtime".  Algorithms have a runtime (running time).  Mathematical expressions do not.  What are you asking?  Are you asking for the asymptotics of that function?  Are you asking for the time complexity to output that value, given $n$ as input?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that, see the updated question.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Properties

Comment: As @D.W. mentioned, a mathematical expression doesn't have a runtime. But if your algorithm costs that much, then it is $\mathcal{O}(n^3 \cdot log^4 n)$. You are left with $n^k$ from ${n \choose k}$ and $log^4 n$ from the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Let us establish a product rule.

Assume that $F(n)=O(f(n))$ and $G(n)=O(g(n))$. This means that

$$\exists N_f,c_f:\forall n\ge N_f: F(n)\le c_f f(n),$$
$$\exists N_g,c_g:\forall n\ge N_g: G(n)\le c_g g(n).$$

From this we draw that, with $N=\max(N_f,N_g)$ and $c=c_fc_g$

$$\exists N,c:\forall n\ge N: F(n)G(n)\le c f(n)g(n).$$

---

Notice that a similar proof holds for the addition.

Answer (score 0):

N over 3 is O(n^3), and log^4(n) is log^4(n). The whole formula is O(n^3 log^4 n). That’s it. Can’t be simplified any further.

It’s asymptotically less than O(n^(3+eps)) for any eps > 0, or less than O(n^3 log^(4+eps) n) or O(n^3 log^4 n log log log n).

Comment: What about $O\left(\frac{\log^4 n!}n\right)$ ?

Comment: Yves, my head almost exploded! Yes, it’s very close.

Comment: It is asymptotically equivalent.